# Labels of cbtics on opposite side of horizontal colorbox

Tags: gnuplot

Suppose I have the following script to make a sort of contourplot.

```
set colorbox horizontal user origin 0.1, 0.9 size 0.8, 0.05
set pm3d map
splot x*y
```

This gives the below result.

[image: Sample image]

Now, what I want to achieve, is that the ticklabels automatically end up on the opposite site of the colorbox. How can I do that?

I tried:

- `set cbtics mirror`, but that doesn't change anything.
- I tried `set cbtics offset 0,3`. And this in principle works, but I would have to adjust it every time.

My `gnuplot` version is 4.6.2

Comment: The options for cbtics are the same as for e.g. xtics, `set cbtics mirror` only draws additional ticks on the opposite side, but doesn't add a label. For the colorbox there is no second axis like the y2tics. So I guess there is no better option than using the `offset`. Maybe it might be more comfortable to use `screen` coordinates instead of `character`, because you also explicitely specify a colorbox height.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a kind of cumbersome workaround using `multiplot`.
It's a bit lengthy, but at least, fiddling around in order to find the proper cbtics label offsets when changing the canvas size should be eliminated.
It works with gnuplot 4.6 (time of the OP's question). With current gnuplot versions it might look slightly different, but can be tuned with the parameters `CBHeight, CBWidth, CBPosX, CBPosY`.

Possible improvements: I haven't found yet how to automatically make the colorbox, e.g. the same width as the graph and center it to the graph by using the `GPVAL_...` variables.

**Code:**

```
### horizontal color bar with xtics on top
reset

set multiplot 

    # actual plot
    unset colorbox
    set size square
    set pm3d map
    set isosamples 100
    set samples 100
    splot sin(1.3*x)*cos(.9*y)+cos(.8*x)*sin(1.9*y)+cos(y*.2*x) notitle

    # horizontal "pseudo" colorbar with tic labels on top 
    # size of colorbox in screen coordinates
    CBHeight = 0.04
    CBWidth  = 0.49
    CBPosX   = (1 - CBWidth)/2   # centered
    CBPosY   = 0.87
    set origin CBPosX,CBPosY
    set size nosquare CBWidth,CBHeight
    set lmargin 0; set tmargin 0; set rmargin 0; set bmargin 0
    unset pm3d
    unset tics
    unset key
    set x2tics out nomirror scale 1.0,0 offset 0,0 
    set colorbox horizontal user origin graph 0, graph 0 size graph 1, graph 1
    set xrange [GPVAL_CB_MIN:GPVAL_CB_MAX]
    plot x palette  # dummy plot
    
unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:** (generated with gnuplot 4.6.0)

[image]